# Swift CollectionView ReloadData Acting Weird

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a Collection View and a button at the top and that button goes through a list of days. For each day, the collection view should be different and I keep track of changes in a dictionary. However, at each press of the button, I want to reload the data, but it's selecting random cells. When data is reloaded, does it run the cellforitematindexpath over again; if not what exactly does it run?

Here's my CellForItem code:

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("availability", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AvailabilityCell
        var tempList: [Int]
        tempList = self.availability[self.days[index]]! as! [Int]
        cell.timeInterval.text = timeIntervals[indexPath.row]
        cell.timePeriod.text = timesForIntervals[indexPath.row]
        cell.timeInterval.textColor = DARK_BLUE
        cell.timePeriod.textColor = DARK_BLUE
        cell.backView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        cell.backView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        cell.backView.layer.borderColor = DARK_BLUE.CGColor
        cell.backView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        cell.selected = false
    if (tempList[indexPath.row] == 1) {

                cell.timeInterval.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                cell.backView.backgroundColor = DARK_BLUE
                cell.timePeriod.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    }
        return cell
    }
```

Here's my Cell Did Select/Deselect:

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! AvailabilityCell
        cell.timeInterval.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        cell.backView.backgroundColor = DARK_BLUE
        cell.timePeriod.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        var tempList: [Int]
        tempList = self.availability[self.days[index]]! as! [Int]
        tempList[indexPath.row] = 1
        self.availability[self.days[index]] = tempList

    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! AvailabilityCell
        cell.timeInterval.textColor = DARK_BLUE
        cell.backView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        cell.timePeriod.textColor = DARK_BLUE
        var tempList: [Int]
        tempList = self.availability[self.days[index]]! as! [Int]
        tempList[indexPath.row] = 0
        self.availability[self.days[index]] = tempList

    }
```

Here's where data is reloaded:

```
@IBAction func decreaseDay(sender: AnyObject) {
        index--
        day.text = days[index]
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.timeCollection.reloadData()
        }
        if (index == 0) {
            back.enabled = false
        }

        forward.enabled = true
    }
```

Here's  a view of what's happening:
How it starts:
[image: How it starts]

When I reload:
[image: What Happens when I reload]

Comment: in your cellForRowatindex method text Background color and backView Backgroung color both are blue thats why this problem occuring

Comment: I don't think that's it because every time i change the background to blue, the text is immediately changed to white and vice versa (there is an if function in cellforrowatindex). But I may not be understanding what you're saying, what exactly is reload data doing?

Comment: Change text lable color like red for testing purpose and reload your tableView try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should change the swift collection view to reload the page on the left hand corner. The data is reloaded to select the most prioritized item in the download list. Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, could you elaborate on what I should change in my code?

Comment: What exactly is the fix?